# Symfony2 UniqueEntity validation constraint as concatenation?

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, symfony-forms

In my `Tag` entity i need to avoid creating a tag with the same `name` along all tags created by a given user. There is a many-to-one relation with `User` entity, named `user`.

I'm enforcing this constraint either in database (using `uniqueConstraints`) and in form validation with `UniqueEntity`. But i can't understand this sentence in [Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) about this constraint:

> This required option is the field (or **list of fields**) on which this
>   entity should be unique. For example, you could specify that both the
>   email and name fields in the User example above should be unique.

But i need that `name` and `user` are **unique as a whole**. Is this possible and how? Here is an example of not working one: both name and user are checked for uniqueness as singular fields.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\HelloBundle\Repository\TagRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     name="tag",
 *     uniqueConstraints={
 *         @ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"name", "user_id"}),
 *     })
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"name", "user"})
 */
class Tag implements TenantableEntityInterface
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=31)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\MaxLength(limit="31")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="tags")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

}
```

**EDIT**: with the definition above the form validates but i get the:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   'name-1' for key 'UNIQ_389B7835E237E06A76ED395'.

Creating two tags with the same `name` and the same user.

Comment: I doubt it's possible in `Symfony` as it targets columns in database and not entity properties. Anyhow, this sounds to me like a job for **triggers**...

Comment: the same trouble here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547001/symfony2-doctrine-uniqueentity-handle-exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the combination of both `name` and `user` be unique, then use:

```
@UniqueEntity(fields={"name", "user"})
```

If you want them be unique separately, use this:

```
@UniqueEntity(fields="name")
@UniqueEntity(fields="user")
```

The same applies for unique constraints on the table.

Comment: It's exactly as i did and it's not working. The form validates but i'm getting a constraint violation from mysql.

Comment: I don't need them to validate separately. Your second option do this, your first option doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache? Are you using the same case when trying the same tag name? What exactly is the error you're getting, if any?

Comment: Cache cleaned, the error is: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'name-1' for key 'UNIQ_389B7835E237E06A76ED395'.

Comment: Solved, thanks. You're right, first solution works. I was calling setUser in the wrong place.

Comment: Good. I ran out of ideas anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just note:

For yaml use:

```
constraints:
    - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
        fields: username
        groups: [SomeYourGroup]
```

Or for annotation:
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

- @UniqueEntity(fields={"username"}, groups={"SomeYourGroup"})

In documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html

groups not available!!!