# Symfony2, Doctrine, @UniqueEntity handle exception

Tags: symfony, exception, doctrine

**ENTITY**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="_apiKey")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Eve\ProfileBundle\Entity\Repository\apiKeyRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"keyID", "vCode", "accountID"}, 
 * message="you already own this api")
 */
class apiKey
{

public function __construct()
{
    // empty
}

// relations start
// relations end

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="entryID", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $entryID;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="accountID", type="integer", nullable=false, unique=true)
 */
private $accountID;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="keyID", type="integer", nullable=false, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="keyID cannot be blank")
 */
private $keyID;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="vCode", type="string", nullable=false, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="vCode cannot be blank")
 */
private $vCode;
```

in db

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `_apiKey` (
  `entryID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `accountID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `keyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vCode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entryID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=18 ;
```

When i try to add dublicate i have an error

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO _apiKey (accountID, keyID, vCode) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params {"1":38,"2":"1233","3":"123"}:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '38-1233-123' for key 'accountID'
```

and it's fine, but how can i handle it? "message option" is not working in **@UniqueEntity()** how can i show this error in form errors (without exception)

what i want (simple example for db without entryID)

```
123 123 123 - add
123 123 1234 - add
123 125 123 - add
123 123 1234 - form-error on inserting
123 123 123 - form-error on inserting
234 123 123 - add
234 123 123 - form-error on inserting
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Duplicate entry '38-1233-123' for **key 'accountID'**

If you want to check the uniqueness of accountId alone, add this to your class:

```
@UniqueEntity(fields={"accountID"}, message="This account is already taken")
```

Here the full code that check the uniqueness of the combinaison "keyID", "vCode", "accountID" and also the uniqueness of "accountID" alone:

```
<?php

// ...

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="_apiKey")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Eve\ProfileBundle\Entity\Repository\apiKeyRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"keyID", "vCode", "accountID"}, message="you already own this api")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"accountID"}, message="This account ID is already taken")
 */
class apiKey
{
```

I don't know if you saw that the error only affect the field accountID, if you don't want this behavior just remove "unique=true" from your property $accountID.

If you just want to say that the cominaison "keyID", "vCode", "accountID" must be unique in the database, proceed like that:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="_apiKey",
 *      uniqueConstraints = {
 *          @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="_api_key_key_id_v_code_account_id", columns={"keyID", "vCode", "accountID})
 *      }
 * )
 *
 * ...
 * etc, ...
 */
class apiKey
```

Comment: i add @UniqueEntity(fields={"keyID", "vCode", "accountID"}, message="you already own this api") and add unique=true - got proper mechanism BUT still no error in form (UniqueEntity - message option not working) why can it be?

Comment: btw it's the same one as shown in question code but message not showing, this message must be in form errors? maybe i misunderstood something

Comment: Yes like I said the error is caused because of only one field: accountID. So you need either remove "unique=true" of the field accountID (to not cause the error), or manage this error by adding @UniqueEntity(fields={"accountID"}, message="This account ID is already taken") to your class if you want accountID unique (alone). The message will be manage in your form so ^^

Comment: i need only "unique combination accountID + keyID + vCode" that's it, NOT ANY other standalone uniques, with error in a form, how can i do it? your example with "* @UniqueEntity(fields={"keyID", "vCode", "accountID"}, message="you already own this api")" and "unique=true" is not showing error message (please show example code i can look at it)

Comment: in question is code with my current example, what i need to change to get form-error for do comnination keyID + vCode + accoundID ? (it will be easier to understand) currently this code works fine (without exceptions) but without form-errors

Comment: changed definition of table (remove uniques to be more clear)

Comment: added simple example what i want (above)

Answer (score 0):

trouble was in form Type class, to work this unique-combination you have to add all values to fields you want to be unique, on my example will be

```
  $builder
            ->add('accountID', 'hidden', array ('data' => $options['acountID']))
            ->add('keyID', 'text')
            ->add('vCode', 'text');
```

i added hidden field (accontID) and fill it with data and then i got proper error to form-errors, if you will not fill there will be null values (so i don't know why it will NOT check uniques)

that is solution for me but basicly @Sybio help meto understand a lot of so i will check his answer as answer ^_^